# Get more than one result from HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl, html-parsing

i'm trying to parse a html file and extract some information and make a statistic of it.

But my Problem is, that HTML::TreeBuilder only returns 1 result but i need all result that are catched by the Regex.

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;


my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
$tree->parse_file('tester.html');
print Dumper($tree->look_down(_tag => 'table',id => qr{post[0-9]*?})->as_HTML);
$tree->delete;
```

tester.html:

```
<table id="post923076">
     <tr>
        <td>table1_result</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="post923076">
    <tr>
       <td>table2_result</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Result:

```
$VAR1 = '<table id="post923076"><tr><td>table1_result</td></tr></table>';
```

Someone an idea?

I have shortened the File for example because the file could content a lot of this tables.

Comment: maybe `->as_HTML` only takes the first element? look_down returns an array.. Try dumping `look_down` without `as_HTML` (so we can see the array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In scalar context, the first result of `look_down` is returned.

You are using in scalar context as a result of chaining `look_down->as_HTML`.

Call in list context then use `map` to translate each element to HTML.

```
print Dumper(map { $_->as_HTML } $tree->look_down(_tag => 'table', id => qr{post[0-9]*?}));
```

Comment: Thx a lot :)
Learning something new to perl.